# Javascript doesn't work as I expect

Tags: javascript

The problem is that when I put the correct hour and the incorrect minutes it always returns me: "bad" and "very nice". I don't know what is going wrong so could you help me please.

I have the following html and JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
       <script language="Javascript">
          var d = new Date();
          var h = d.getHours();
          var h1 = document.forms["INICI"].starthour.value;
          var m = d.getMinutes();
          var m1 = document.forms["INICI"].startminut.value;

          function myHour() {
               if ( h==h1 ) {
                   document.write("nice"+"<br>");
               } else {
                   document.write("bad"+"<br>");
               }
          }

          function myMinut() {
               if ( m1==m ){
               document.write("very nice"+"<br>");
               } else {
               document.write("very bad"+"<br>")
              }
          }
          </script>

          <form name="INICI">
          start hour: <input name="starhour"/> <br />
          <br>
          start minut: <input name="startminut"/> <br />
          <input id="insert1" 
                 onclick="myHour(); myMinut();" 
                 type="submit" 
                 value="Click" />
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

(I'm new here.... sorry if I did this post  very bad)

Comment: your updating your javascript variable from html elements values with out checking if the html element already loaded. remove your script to the end of the body tag.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer. It will look better for your profile that you mark correct answers

Comment: The language attribute for script elements was deprecated a very long time ago and removed from HTML5. Just use `<script>...</script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had improved your code. here is a working version of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form name="INICI">
        start hour:
        <input name="starthour" />
        <br />
        <br>
        start minut:
        <input name="startminut" />
        <br />
        <input id="insert1" onclick="EvaluateResults()" type="submit" value="Click" />
    </form>

    <script language="Javascript">
        function EvaluateResults() {
            var d = new Date();
            var h = d.getHours();
            var h1 = document.forms["INICI"].starthour.value;
            var m = d.getMinutes();
            var m1 = document.forms["INICI"].startminut.value;

            console.log(h + ' ' + h1);


            if (h == h1) {
                document.write("nice" + "<br>");
            }
            else {
                document.write("bad" + "<br>");
            }

            if (m1 == m) {
                document.write("very nice" + "<br>");
            }
            else {
                document.write("very bad" + "<br>")
            }


        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What went wrong with your code is that you are taking the time when the JavaScript file loaded and executed and not when the button is pressed. What i did to solve your problem is I just created a method and transferred the code that acquires the time.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your variables when the page loads so they will always be the same.

If you put them inside the functions this could be solved

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();


function myHour()
{
    var h1 = document.forms["INICI"].starthour.value;
    if (h==h1){
     document.write("nice"+"<br>");
    }
    else{
        document.write("bad"+"<br>");
    }
}

function myMinut()
{
    var m1 = document.forms["INICI"].startminut.value;
    if (m1==m){
        document.write("very nice"+"<br>");
    }
    else{
        document.write("very bad"+"<br>")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
<input name="starhour"/>
```

Needed

```
<input name="starthour"/>
```

Also put your script tag to the end of the body